# Ag Grid Infinite Scrolling

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, ag-grid, infinite-scroll, infinity

I am Implementing Ag-grid for infinite scrolling, the problem I am facing is when we hit API for data it returns all data. what I want is that if we scroll down it then hit API to bring the next data. But in ag-grid, all data comes in one go and saves in our browser memory.

Do we have any solution for that like when I scroll down then only API should hit and next data come in our grid.

Answer (score 0):

Check the example provided in [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-infinite-scrolling/#simple-example-no-sorting-or-filtering). Try switching `Example version` to `React/Angular` as per you requirement.

You can control `how much data to be loaded/cached to the browser` and how API calls should work by below `props` (in case of `React`)

```js
rowBuffer: 0,
rowModelType: 'infinite',
paginationPageSize: 100,
cacheOverflowSize: 2,
maxConcurrentDatasourceRequests: 1,
infiniteInitialRowCount: 1000,
maxBlocksInCache: 10,
```